# Fixed nav and anchor

Tags: jquery, fixed, anchor-scroll

I have a navbar at top. When page loads, it is 'relative'. If I scroll. it changes to 'fixed'. There is an issue with anchors on page. When page loads and I am at top of page, clicking link to an anchor scrolls me to section and a part of it is hidden. When I click the same link in that position, it scrolls to the top of section correct.

What can I do to fix that problem?

The HTML

```
<nav id="fixedmenu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#brends">Brends</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
...
<section id="brends"></section>
```

The javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
     var target = $(this.hash);
     if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
     if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 800);
     return false;
    });
   });
```

and

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var div = $('#fixedmenu');
    var start = $(div).offset().top;
    var wnd = $(document).width();
    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
     var p = $(window).scrollTop();
     $(div).css('position',( (p) > start && wnd > 319 ) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
     $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
     $(div).width($('.container').width());
     $(div).css('box-shadow', '0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4');
    });
   });
```

UPD: Solved in this way

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
     var target = $(this.hash);
     if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
     if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
     var menuheight = $('#fixedmenu').height();
     var ofs = ( $('#fixedmenu').css('position') == 'fixed' ) ? menuheight : menuheight * 2;
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - ofs }, 800);
     return false;
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is to do with the fixed-nav. When an element if fixed, it is removed from the DOM and sits over top of it. Therefore all content moves up by the height of the nav bar.

What you need to do is to apply a padding to your body  in css, which ids the height of your nav bar and your page will scroll correctly to the anchors.

eg: if the nav bar is 50px high:

```
body{padding-top:50px}
```

or to each section:

```
 section{padding-top:50px}
```

depending on what your page looks like - you may want to set the padding  only when the nav is fixed and remove it when it is relative. Or you may just keep the padding on and have breathing room at the top of your section.

Another way to achieve this is to remove an offset to the offset.top in your code:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50}, 800);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Javascript works fine, but first click if I am on top of page and nav is 'relative' scrolls directly to anchor and a part of section is behind nav, what became fixed. Then it works fine.

Comment: OMG, all I had to do was: var ofs = ( $('#fixedmenu').css('position') == 'fixed' ) ? menuheight : menuheight * 2; and then deduct ofs...

Comment: nice! I am guessing that you are using ofs as an offset - this goes to what I was trying to say - when the nav is fixed you have to account for the space that it would nomally take up in the dom and adjust the offset accrodinlgy. well done1